# Simple liquid markup for Shopify not working ...?

Tags: if-statement, shopify, liquid

I made this simple markup on a Shopify product-template.liquid section. It's not returning the second image though on different products outside of the ones specified.

```
{% if product.handle == "e" or "f" %}

{{ '3.png' | asset_url | img_tag }}

{% else %}

{{ '4.png' | asset_url | img_tag }}

{% endif %}
```

This seems pretty straight forward according to [Shopify's documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/control-flow-tags#else-elsif). However I can't get 4.png to come up on the other products in the store.

This seems like a really basic problem, but it's doing me in! What am I missing?

Comment: This is not a valid if statement `{% if product.handle == "e" or "f" %}`. Your second statement ALWAYS return `true`.

Comment: Problem is the first statement (3.png) is always coming back. What is the correct way if this is not a valid statement? It looks valid according to the Shopify docs.

Comment: You are checking the string "f" .. for nothing. So you are checking a non-empty string that always return true. The correct way to write this is `{% if product.handle == "e" or product.handle == "f" %}`

Comment: It worked. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't chain conditional statements in liquid you need to redefine the comparison.

```
{% if product.handle == "e" or product.handle == "f" %}
  {{ '3.png' | asset_url | img_tag }}
{% else %}
  {{ '4.png' | asset_url | img_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @user4889134 Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Be sure to mark this as the correct answer to the question so people understand that it is solved.